# google maps on android 9 crash "Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/ProtocolVersion"

Tags: android, google-maps, windev

I'm creating simple map application with Windev mobile development suite. Here is the problem.

- My google key is correct.
- I'm using API 28.
- Compilation is okay.

But at launch it crashes.

```
Message=Didn't find class "org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion" on path: DexPathList
```

Google play services are installed. regarding the manifest file i added in the  section:

```
    <uses-library
    android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
    android:required="false" />
```

Thanks in advance for any useful help :-)

Comment: You need to check out the crash details as instructed in [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this).

Comment: post full logcat trace here

Comment: [link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/16AFKh4BNuwmncVnd27LepYdObyhM4sje/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Anyway in the logcat trace we find again : 2020-07-31 10:22:58.589 19813-19853/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3
    Process: com.proteck.inter_proteck, PID: 19813
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/ProtocolVersion;

Comment: Did you add the above Apache library exactly inside the `<application>` tag, without any nested elements? What version of google play services do you use?